# rest web api 2 makes a call to action method without invoked

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api2

I am following a tutorial located here:     https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html
and i am running the web api in iis express and call it using postman with the following path:
http://localhost:5056/api/todo
this call hits the constructor and then somehow calls the 
   `GetAll` function which is never called and does not even have `HttpGet` verb. **How is it getting called?**

```
namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TodoController : Controller
    {
        public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoItems)
        {
            TodoItems = todoItems;
        }

        public IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetAll()
        {
            return TodoItems.GetAll();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name="GetTodo")]
        public IActionResult GetById(string id)
        {
            var item = TodoItems.Find(id);
            if (item == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            return new ObjectResult(item);
        }

        public  ITodoRepository TodoItems { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Some code might help

Comment: updated the question with code. i don't understand why the downvote. i am trying to understand something. honest question guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All methods in the controller are per default HttpGet. You don't need to specify the HttpGet verb explicit. 
If you are using the default route specified in the WebApiConfig and call the http://localhost:5056/api/todo it will route to the first parameterless function in the controller. In your case GetAll().

If you want to specify the routing you can use the attributes RoutePreFix and Route

```
namespace TodoApi.Controllers
{
[RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")]
public class TodoController : Controller
{
    public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoItems)
    {
        TodoItems = todoItems;
    }
    Route("First")]
    public IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetAll1()
    {
        return TodoItems.GetAll();
    }

    [Route("Second")]
    public IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetAll2()
    {
        return TodoItems.GetAll();
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name="GetTodo")]
    public IActionResult GetById(string id)
    {
        var item = TodoItems.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
            return HttpNotFound();
        return new ObjectResult(item);
    }

    public  ITodoRepository TodoItems { get; set; }

}
```

And to call the methods:

http://localhost:5056/api/todo/first

http://localhost:5056/api/todo/second

You can read more about it [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Comment: what if you have two methods? how does it choose which one to pick?