# WebApi - Multiple GET actions with identical signatures - routing issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

**Question Background:**

I have a single controller within my WebApi that has two action methods. These two actions methods are both GET's and have no parameters.

One action method is named 'GetMessages', the other 'GetEmployeeList'.

**The Issue:**

These are the following action Methods in my Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public string GetMessages()
{
  return "Get Messages Endpoint";
}

[HttpGet]
public string GetEmployeeList()
{
    return "Get Employees Endpoint";
}
```

These are the customs routes I have set with the WepApiConfig

```
  config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "Messages",
  routeTemplate: "v2/api/People/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { action = "GetMessages", id = RouteParameter.Optional });


   config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "Employees",
   routeTemplate: "v2/api/People/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { action = "GetEmployeeList", id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

When I call either pf the following URL's:

```
/v2/api/People/GetMessages
/v2/api/People/GetEmployeeList
```

I receieve the following exception messaging stating that multiple actions match the URL request:

```
Multiple actions were found that match the request: System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage GetMessages() on type Persons.PeopleController System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage GetEmployeeList() on Persons.PeopleController
```

How Can I rectify this so I an use two GET action methods together which have the same signature?

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37608637/rest-web-api-2-makes-a-call-to-action-methond-without-invoked/37608831#37608831

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I might not be getting the point, but why don't you simply adjust the routes like this (please notice the action names in the route templates):

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "Messages",
  routeTemplate: "v2/api/People/GetMessages/{id}",
  defaults: new { action = "GetMessages", id = RouteParameter.Optional });

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "Employees",
   routeTemplate: "v2/api/People/GetEmployeeList/{id}",
   defaults: new { action = "GetEmployeeList", id = RouteParameter.Optional});
```

However I would rather go with a more generic option:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
  name: "People",
  routeTemplate: "v2/api/People/{action}/{id}",
  defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });
```

This way you can cover both of the actions with a single route. Is there any reason not to choose this option?

Answer (score 1):

What about specifying route for every method separately?

```
[RoutePrefix("api/people")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("messages")]
    public string GetMessages()
    {
      return "Get Messages Endpoint";
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("employees")]
    public string GetEmployeeList()
    {
        return "Get Employees Endpoint";
    }
}
```

so you will the have your URLs like

```
/v2/api/people/messages
/v2/api/people/employees
```

which IMHO looks a bit more RESTful than your example

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to have two routes. One is enough. Try changing your route to the following.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

You can try to specify your routes separately, but you shouldnt have to. Make sure your call to the web api is 100% correct.